# n Dimensional Rotation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

So the rotation matrix for 2D is:

\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}

and one of three BASIC rotation matrices for 3D is:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}

but what is the general form of a rotation matrix for $N>3$ dimensions?

Assuming the pattern stays the same, on of the possible $n$-rotation matrices for an $N$-dimensional rotation matrix could be:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & 0 & -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}

Does this even seem right? I need to be able to rotate any possible $N$-by-$N$ matrix by the $N$-dim. rotation matrix through any angle.

Comment: What precisely, does "rotation matrix" mean here, and what does  rotating a matrix mean?

Comment: @kimchilover https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: “One of three rotation matrices...” There are many other rotations in 3-D—an infinite number of them, in fact—besides rotations about the standard coordinate axes. The situation becomes even more complex in higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @amd The three 'Basic' 3D rotation matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: This paper may help. It looks like it presents an algorithm for constructing n-dimensional rotation matrices. http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2004/Papers_2004_Short/N29.pdf

Answer (score 6):

As explained by a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3698979/42553), what you want is a linear transformation $A:X\rightarrow X$ on finite dimensional inner product space $X$ that preserves amplitude of vectors, and angle between vectors. Namely,

1. $\|Ax\|=\|x\|,\ \forall x\in X$
2. $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle,\ \forall x,y\in X$

In fact, we can introduce the following additional conditions,

3. $A^\ast A=I$
4. $AA^\ast=I$

and show that 1, 2, 3 and 4 are equivalent (see Theorem 2.9 in Functional Analysis by Bachman and Narici, Dover Publication, 2000).

This happen to be the definition of the **unitary matrix**. Note that the determinant of unitary matrix could be $1$ or $-1$. The only extra condition to throw in to exclude “flipping” so that we are left with “rotation” only is

5. $\det(A)=1$.

So back to your question, how can one generate a matrix that rotates the underlying vector space by an arbitrary angle? Here is an idea.

Start with the identity matrix $I$, and suppose the desired rotation rotates the $j^\text{th}$ column of $I$ denoted $I_j$ to $v$ (with $\|v\|=1$ obviously). Assuming $\langle I_j, v\rangle\neq 0$, then what you can do is

1. Move $I_j$ to the first column and replace it with $v$
2. Perform Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization on the resulted matrix, starting from the $2^\text{nd}$ column
3. Swap the $1^\text{st}$ column and the $j^\text{th}$ column to resume the original order

The resulted matrix $A$ satisfies $A^\ast A=I$ by the nature of Gram-Schmidt process, therefore is a rotation. And it transforms $I_j$ to $v$, thus giving you the desired rotation.

Comment: Do you know any methods of creating rotation matrices using the same form I gave in my question, with various 'cos', 'sin' ?

Comment: Only when the rotation is strictly in 2-dimension can you use $cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta)$ to represent it nicely. A rotation in 3-dimension in general cannot be represented by a single angle. Did you try the method I showed? It's quite elementary.

Answer (score 3):

The distance preserving linear maps $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ are precisely the ones which satisfy $T^*T=I$. It would be appropriate to call distance preserving linear maps as 'rotations.' If one wants to further preserve orientation then one would in addition demand $\det(T) > 0$ (note that this forces $\det(T) = 1$).

In matrix language, an $n\times n$ real matrix $M$ is a rotation matrix if $M^tM=I$, where $M^t$ is the transpose of $M$.

Comment: good stuff but I wanted application (how to do)

Comment: @notMyName You were inquiring as to what is the general form of a rotation matrix. This is the best I can say.