# Rotate randomly in 6 dimensions with uniform sampling

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to rotate several vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$ by the same rotation matrix $M$. $M$ should be random but uniformly sample the rotation space. I know that the $6\times6$ length-preserving rotation matrix $M$ must fulfill $M^T=M^{-1}$ and for preservation of orientation we would additionally require $\text{det}(M)=1$ ([Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3698979/737314)). How can I calculate these random matrices? How to achieve random matrices with uniform random sampling?

I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839179/737314) to calculate uniformly sampled random vectors but I also need the rotation matrix as I want to apply the same transformation several times.

Comment: I think uniform in all directions and uniform on all matrices are the same, and thus the link you post shall solve your problem.

Comment: @VezenBU I think the answer there is only about random vectors but I need also the rotation matrix. I clarified my post.

Comment: Hi@granularbastard : combining the two answers in the post you link, should suggest that in the QR decomposition of a Gaussian Matrix, the Q matrix is uniformly distributed on the sphere